# Grep strings ending with string and bracket

Tags: bash, regex, grep

I have an array and then the following loop:

```
for i in "${familyNames[@]}"
do 
  name=`echo "$i"`
  cat $file | grep -E \("$name"[[:blank:]]\|[[:blank:]]"$name"[[:blank:]]\|[[:blank:]]"$name"\) >> .fitnam.log

  nameFem=`echo "$name"ova`
  cat $file | grep -E \("$nameFem"[[:blank:]]\|[[:blank:]]"$nameFem"[[:blank:]]\|[[:blank:]]"$nameFem"\) >> .fitnam.log
done
```

And the input file would be something like:

```
Smith John(johnsmith)
Smith Jane(janesmith)
Bauer Jack(jackbauer)
Long Jackson(jackslo)
```

Let's say I'm looking for string `Jack`. The problem is that the output would also include `Long Jackson`. So I need for the last part of `[[:blank:]]"$name"` to include `(`.

`[[:blank:]]"$name"(*` doesn't work due to syntax error.

`[[:blank:]]"$name""("*` doesn't work due to unmatched parentheses.

`[[:blank:]]"$name"\(*` doesn't work due to unmatched parentheses either.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use word boundaries

```
grep '\<Jack\>' file
```

or with double quotes

```
grep "\\<$name\\>" file
```

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html#grep-regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 0):

To search for personal names (first names):

```
$ name=Jack; grep -E "[[:blank:]]$name[(]" file
Bauer Jack(jackbauer)
```

To search only for family names:

```
$ name=Bauer; grep -E "^$name[[:blank:]]" file
Bauer Jack(jackbauer)
```

To search for either a first name or a family name:

```
$ name=Jack; grep -E "^$name[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]$name[(]" file
Bauer Jack(jackbauer)
$ name=Bauer; grep -E "^$name[[:blank:]]|[[:blank:]]$name[(]" file
Bauer Jack(jackbauer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key point of your requestion is that the search keyword (e.g. `Jack`) must be trailing with `(`, and can has blank space at front of it, but not necessary.

Maybe you could use `sed` and `awk` to solve it.

Via sed

```
name='Jack'
sed -r -n '/[[:space:]]*'"${name}"'\(/p' file
```

Via awk

```
name='Jack'
awk 'match($0,/[[:space:]]*'"${name}"'\(/){print}' file
```